# input lose focus inside a HOC component

Tags: reactjs

I wrapper textarea in a component Wrapper.js which will dynamically add html element around the children.

However, the children(textarea) loses it's focus as the wrapper re-renders?
How to fix this issue?

- **autoFocus={true}** won't work. it will set the cursor to the first character in the input.

```
function Wrapper({value, children}){
  if(value?.length>5){
    return (
      <>
        <span> too loong </span>
        {children}
        </>
    );
  }    
  return children;
}

function Counter(){
   const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useState('');
   const counterValueHandler = (e) => {
     setCounterValue(e?.target?.value);
   }
  return (
    <Wrapper value={counterValue}>
      <h1> Counter </h1>
      <input value={counterValue} onChange={counterValueHandler} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}


  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

## Got the root cause. cuz I have a label before textarea which doesn't make any sense. Any idea?

```
               **<label htmlFor="basicpill-excerpt-input">Example</label>**
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mvsc8c?file=index.tsx

Comment: [Setting focus in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Please run your code through a Prettier.

Comment: Also, please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It might be noteworthy that this only happens if the textarea is after the span. If the span follows the children, the focus is kept intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your scenario on Stackblitz here:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1fytfg?file=index.tsx

Notice that only the first variant fails to preserve the focus when entering text.

It seems that adding a proper `key` to the `textarea` fixes the problem without having to change the order of the elements.

So you probably have something else which lets your textarea loose its focus.

**Update**:

When the content embedded in the `WrapperBefore` contains more than the `textarea`, the focus still gets lost.

I was able to fix that by avoiding creating multiple different element trees returned by the wrapper component:

Instead of

```
if (condition) {
    return <>
        {children}
        <div>Warning</div>
    </>;
}

return <>{children}</>;
```

I then wrote

```
return <>
    {children}
    {condition ? <div>Warning</div> : null}
</>;
```

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vhvdgc?file=index.tsx

Comment: I didn't know what the heck is happening on my codebase. But your solution is same as my case.

Comment: Got the root cause. cuz I have a label before textarea which doesn't make any sense. Any idea?

                   **<label htmlFor="basicpill-excerpt-input">Example</label>**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mvsc8c?file=index.tsx

Comment: @newBike: it's not even about the label - any element added into the wrapper contents causes the problem; fixed by not returning different trees from the Wrapper component.